# How to specify default access in spring security?

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security 4 and I realized that if I add a url handler in the controller and forget to specify access rights in spring security xml , this page will not be secured and will be accessible to all. I was trying to use:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
```

But it bans all users, even those I specifically open access to in other  tags.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you think about something like that?

```
access="isAuthenticated()"
```

as said [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) it returns true if the user is not anonymous.

I think the main idea of keeping app secure is not to make mistakes by human too... Even the best security system is not secure when human forgot to set a password.

Comment: Yes, this is better than nothing. But is it so that I cannot specify that I want to close access to anything except what I specifically marked as open?